# Display clicks for each user

Tags: php, mysql

So I learn PHP, and I want to try to build something like a small monetized url shortener, just for fun! So every time somebody clicks on a users link, one click should be added in the MySQL table (for the user). I tried a lot of scripts but they all don't work.

```
<html lang="en-US">
<?php
$servername = "***";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "***";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET 'hits' = 'hits'+1 WHERE id = 1");

?>
```

And after then display the clicks in the users dashboard via $row['']... but it doesn't count the clicks when I onload the page... the number in the mysql database does'nt change... what am I doing wrong. Alsom do you have and more professional idea how to do that, cause I know that this isn't a good alternative... I also have something like that , but it doesnt work too...

```
      $user_ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      $check_ip = mysqli_query("select userip from pageview where page='1' and userip='$user_ip'");
      if(mysqli_num_rows($check_ip)>=1)
      {

      }
      else
      {
        mysqli_query("insert into pageview values('1','1','$user_ip')");
         mysqli_query("update users set 'hits' = 'hits'+1 where id=1 ");

  }
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: You're using the wrong notation for the column `hits`. Try removing the single quotes, they're not necessary. If you do need to escape a column name, use backticks.

Comment: mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET `hits` = `hits`+1 WHERE id = 1");
I tried this but it doesn't work too

Comment: I tried to do it with these `

Comment: I removed them but it is still not working

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't enough detail. Do you get an error? Does this work via the `mysql` command-line?

Comment: [12-May-2017 21:50:52 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/viidsu/public_html/vKeeR/index.php on line 16

Comment: UPDATE users SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE id = 1 tried this trough mysql console and it worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're used to `mysql_query`, you need to do this differently, a connection handle is required, no longer implicit. The best way to avoid slipping up on this is to use the object-oriented calling method:

```
$conn->query(...);
```

This approach is often substantially less verbose.

Comment: could you go more into detail

Comment: IT WORKED <3 but do you think there is a more professional way, cause I dont think big sites would do it like that

Comment: "Big sites" use different database drivers and so on, but the fundamentals are the same.